# Moving a tensor to cuda device cause illegal memory access in Pytorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, google-colaboratory

I am trying the following snippet in Colab but causes the following error.
Is it wrong to move a tensor object to Cuda device?.

```
import torch
a = torch.Tensor(torch.randn(5,5,5))
# a.device("cuda")
device = torch.device("cuda")
class abc(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.w1 = torch.nn.Linear(5,5)

    def forward(self,x):
        return self.w1(x)
mod = abc()
a.cuda()
mod.to(device)
mod(a)
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-5372fb4d5512> in <module>()
     11         return self.w1(x)
     12 mod = abc()
---> 13 a.cuda()
     14 mod.to(device)
     15 mod(a)

RuntimeError: CUDA error: an illegal memory access was encountered
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me on Google colab:

```py
import torch
a = torch.randn(5,5,5)
a = a.to("cuda") # or just a = torch.randn((5,5,5), device='cuda')

class abc(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.w1 = torch.nn.Linear(5,5)

    def forward(self,x):
        return self.w1(x)
mod = abc()
mod.to("cuda")
mod(a)
```

Output:

```
tensor([[[ 1.5691e+00,  8.0326e-01,  1.4352e+00,  7.3295e-01,  3.2156e-01],
         [ 5.1630e-01, -2.2816e-03,  7.1052e-01,  1.9250e-01,  8.3110e-01],
         [ 7.6572e-01, -8.9701e-01,  2.7974e-01,  7.4309e-04,  9.5218e-01],
         [ 2.0723e-01, -1.0049e+00,  1.6938e+00,  1.0019e+00,  7.9305e-01],
         [-1.0973e-02, -1.1260e-01,  1.0521e+00, -1.3839e-01, -4.2380e-01]],

        [[ 1.3870e+00,  1.1620e+00, -3.6523e-01, -5.6704e-01,  4.2481e-01],
         [ 1.6204e-01,  8.3231e-02, -5.9607e-01, -1.0912e+00, -6.1651e-01],
         [ 2.3584e-01, -5.9825e-01,  1.1670e+00,  9.3185e-01,  4.0269e-01],
         [ 1.3120e+00,  1.3967e-01, -5.5048e-01, -9.8143e-01,  3.5059e-01],
         [ 8.0019e-01, -1.8983e-02,  2.3792e-01, -5.9157e-01,  3.5816e-01]],

        [[ 3.9709e-01, -8.7349e-01, -2.9742e-01, -3.8732e-01, -1.7191e-03],
         [-8.7056e-01, -8.8214e-01,  1.0647e+00,  7.7785e-01,  6.3816e-01],
         [ 7.4920e-01, -4.0143e-01,  5.9780e-01,  2.7842e-01,  8.1991e-01],
         [-5.9389e-02, -4.9465e-01, -3.7322e-03, -7.0475e-01, -2.5955e-01],
         [ 1.5722e+00,  6.4410e-01, -5.1310e-02, -1.2716e+00, -1.4607e-01]],

        [[ 6.5152e-02, -6.8772e-01,  1.0366e+00, -2.4278e-01, -2.7106e-01],
         [ 7.0832e-01,  1.4581e-01,  1.9924e-01, -4.1930e-01,  4.0567e-01],
         [ 3.9120e-01, -1.0099e+00,  1.6907e+00,  7.2674e-01,  6.5285e-01],
         [-1.3191e-01, -8.6324e-01, -1.2734e-01, -5.6135e-01, -4.1949e-01],
         [ 5.4183e-02, -5.6837e-01,  5.1347e-02, -5.3199e-01,  2.2167e-01]],

        [[ 9.9237e-02, -5.8725e-01, -3.3042e-01, -8.7371e-01, -2.3261e-01],
         [ 5.5485e-01, -3.5022e-01,  1.1516e-01,  3.8139e-02,  4.6032e-01],
         [-7.5111e-01, -9.7203e-01,  1.7809e-01,  2.2506e-01,  3.6540e-02],
         [ 2.5590e-01,  3.0592e-01,  6.8972e-01,  1.8452e-01,  6.7794e-01],
         [-7.6091e-01, -1.3956e+00,  7.8801e-01, -1.7489e-01, -1.0143e+00]]],
       device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)
```

Comment: Still, I don't know why this error happens. I pasted the code in a new notebook in Colab with GPU runtime, it worked fine. But not in the previous notebook. I restarted the runtime in it. Then only it worked.

Comment: alter the "torch.Tensor" to "torch.tensor" in your original example and you will get the warning: "UserWarning: To copy construct from a tensor, it is recommended to use sourceTensor.clone().detach() or sourceTensor.clone().detach().requires_grad_(True), rather than torch.tensor(sourceTensor).". This may be the clue, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

actually if we run the code, we may get the result if we run the code here.

> RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu!

and then, if we enter a.cuda(), we will get

> RuntimeError: CUDA error: an illegal memory access was encountered

So may the tensor forward in the model, but it failed, it could be handled in some computation, and then it's not able to transfer to cuda again.

I guess so, but I do not know what the model(nn.Module) forward do to the tensor.

BTW, this is a simple problem here, but if we met in some complex problem, we can find if we have make the same mistake here **(forward tensor to cuda again)**